# Horror where monkeys would call people on the phone and then go to their house and kill them

Tags: story-identification, horror

Trying to identify a movie:

Monkeys (or someone) would call people on the phone and say something like, "Sarah, we want you" in a creepy voice. Then monkeys would show up at the person's house and at least one of the people in the house would end up strung up on a meat hook.

> I don't recall the origin of the monkeys, but they were the main horror device in the movie — eye witness testimony.

This would have been late 1970s. Probably rented, as it is hard to imagine that kind of horror on TV. (Betamax and VHS were available, so who knows?)

Comment: It's a new kind of call center!

Comment: @OrganicMarble : At least this one sends someone over to your house *promptly*.

Comment: I have not found the movie yet, but I've come upon many weird and wonderful movies while looking for horror movies involving monkeys, so I really can't say the time has been wasted.

Comment: Why does [this list](http://www.chillertv.com/friday13/13-amazing-horror-movies-starring-monkeys) exist!?

Comment: ...well, why not?  :)

Comment: Engineer Toast, because "Everything's Better with Monkeys" Look that up on the web for added proof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is "[Don't Be Afraid of the Dark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_Be_Afraid_of_the_Dark_(1973_film))" from 1973.

The wikipedia description seems to fit quite nicely:

> **Sally** soon begins to feel unsettled in the house. One night while
>   sleeping, she is woken by voices whispering her name, and an ashtray
>   mysteriously falls off her bedside cabinet. However, Alex dismisses
>   her concerns and believes she is suffering from nervous tension. The
>   next evening, when she is alone in the house, something grabs her
>   dress as she is walking down the stairs and she hears voices
>   whispering "**We want you**". She manages to free herself and sees
>   something scuttling away behind a curtain, which she believes was a
>   small animal of some kind. Soon afterwards, she hears the same
>   whispering coming from behind the fireplace in the basement den. When
>   Alex returns home, he remains unconvinced of her story, but makes sure
>   the fireplace is bolted securely shut to reassure her.
>
> The following night, Sally throws a dinner party for Alex's work
>   colleagues as he is up for partnership at his law firm. During the
>   party, **Sally sees a small, hideous goblin-like creature near her leg
>   under the dinner table.** She screams, but nobody believes what she saw
>   as the creature quickly vanishes. Alex grows impatient with her and
>   thinks she is becoming delusional. Later, while Sally is in the
>   shower, three of the goblin creatures make their way into the bathroom
>   and turn out the lights so that they can attack her with a razor. As
>   Sally turns the light back on, the creatures shriek and retreat from
>   the brightness into the bathroom cupboards where they disappear. Sally
>   then tells Alex that they should sell the house.

Comment: There is a shocking lack of meat hooks in this description.

Comment: Aw... I saw this one, but didn't think they were sufficiently monkey-like, and also noted the lack of meat hooks.